# Implementation of optical flow using CNN by tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to implement *FlowNetCorr model*  in Figure 2 on 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06852 , by Tensorflow.

Although I know the basic implementation of LeNet or Alexnet, it is hard to write more complex models.

I don't know how to implement correlation layer and  by Tensorflow. Is there any recommendation material or suggestion?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using this op: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution